# SPARK 2.0: spark-infotheoretic-feature-selection java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, feature-selection, spark-packages

I am trying to use MRMR feature of InfoGain third-party (https://github.com/sramirez/spark-infotheoretic-feature-selection) package of Spark. But my cluster is 2.0 and I am getting this exception. Even though I added all the required Jar files to spark class path. But still it is not working. Although it's working on local machine properly but not on cluster.

Exception:

```
18/03/29 01:16:43 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 47, EUREDWORKER3): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix$.canMapValues(Lscala/reflect/ClassTag;)Lbreeze/generic/UFunc$UImpl2;
at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.InfoTheorySparse$$anonfun$15.apply(InfoTheory.scala:172)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.InfoTheorySparse$$anonfun$15.apply(InfoTheory.scala:172)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$mapValues$1$$anonfun$apply$43$$anonfun$apply$44.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:759)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$mapValues$1$$anonfun$apply$43$$anonfun$apply$44.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:759)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:214)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:926)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:866)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:926)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:670)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:332)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:926)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:866)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:926)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:670)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[Reference for Spark class path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp0U5.jpg)

Comment: Any chance you're using an out-ofe of the -date or incompatible version of one of the jar files?

Comment: Yes, it was problem of version of breeze. I was adding old version breeze_2.11_0.11 by changing it to  0.13.2 solved the problem. Thanks for pointing me the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem with the version of breeze. I was adding an old version breeze_2.11_0.11 and by changing it to breeze_2.11-0.13.2.jar solved the problem.